# Is it possible to pass a javascript function in the scope parameter of the Collection.map_reduce in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Given:

```
jstrMap = """
function() {
  print("isPointInside = " + isPointInside);
  print("polygon = " + polygon);
  emit(this._id, this);
}
"""
jstrReduce = """
function(key, values) {
  return values[0];
}
"""

def readJSCodeFromFile(filePath):
  with open(filePath) as f:
    return Code(f.read())

jsIsPointInside = readJSCodeFromFile(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'IsPointInside.js'))
```

IsPointInside.js:

```
function(pt, poly) {
}
```

And I invoke map_reduce like this:

```
mycoll.map_reduce(jstrMap, jstrReduce, 'results',
    scope = {'isPointInside': jsIsPointInside, 'polygon': [[-77, 39], [-77,38], [-78,38], [-78,39]]})
```

Here is what I get on the client console:

```
db assertion failure, assertion: 'map invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: isPointInside is not a function nofile_b:3', assertionCode: 9014
```

And the server output is:

```
isPointInside = null
polygon = -77,39,-77,38,-78,38,-78,39
Sun Apr 01 16:29:14 [conn11] JS Error: TypeError: isPointInside is not a function nofile_b:3
Sun Apr 01 16:29:14 [conn11] mr failed, removing collection :: caused by :: 9014 map invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: isPointInside is not a function nofile_b:3
```

Debugging the python code reveals that `jsIsPointInside` is of type `Code`, as expected. `str(jsIsPointInside)` returns the function text, i.e. 'function(pt, poly) {\n}\n'

I do not want to populate the system.js collection, I'd like to pass the function in the scope. Is it possible at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Scope is an object where the fields are placed in the MapReduce scope as variables w/ the field name.

If you'd like to put a function in scope, you need to make it a value a field e.g.

```
scope = {
    myFunc: function() { return "Foo";} 
}
```

Comment: My client code is python. I cannot use the javascript syntax. And using the python syntax I am doing what you are suggesting - notice the 'isPointInside' scope parameter. It just does not work.

Comment: The map_reduce command takes kwargs, one of which could be scope.